# Mysql insert multiple records based on another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have

```
Table User with fields: Id, Name
Table Template with fields: Id, DefaultField, user_id
```

For every Id in User, i need to add 3 default rows to Template table.
Example:

```
User Table has:
1   |  "John Doe"
2   |  "Alan Smith"
```

In my Template table i should have

```
1  | "Name" | 1
2  | "Email" | 1
3  | "Contact Number" | 1
4  | "Name" | 2
5  | "Email" | 2
6  | "Contact Number" | 2
```

I wish to do like following but the second query wont work if first query is executed

```
INSERT INTO template (name, user_id)
SELECT 'Name', id
FROM user
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM template)

INSERT INTO template (name, user_id)
SELECT 'Email', id
FROM user
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM template)

INSERT INTO template (name, user_id)
SELECT 'Contact Number', id
FROM user
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM template)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a `CROSS JOIN` should do.

```
insert into template (name, user_id)
select t.name, u.id
from user u cross join (
    select 'Name' name union all
    select 'Email' name union all
    select 'Contact Number' name
) t where not exists (
    select 1
    from template z
    where u.id = z.user_id
);
```

If you are doing it the very first time and there is no record in template table then you can get rid of the where clause in the above.